# Does Blood in the Water work if I score a critical hit on something immune to critical hits?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, critical-hit, combat-maneuver, immunities

Blood in the Water (*Tome of Battle*, p. 86) states:

> While you are in this stance, you whip yourself into a terrible rage. When you score a critical hit against an opponent, you enter a near frenzied state from the sight and smell of blood. You gain a +1 bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls. Because this is an untyped bonus, it stacks with each successful critical hit you score.
>
> If you go more than 1 minute without achieving a critical hit, you no longer gain the benefit of the stance.

Does this work if I score a critical hit on something immune to critical hits?

The description doesn't state that I have to damage the creature with a critical hit. This isn't precision damage that can only be done to something that is deigned their Dex bonus.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did some additional digging. Magic Items and Critical Hits (*Dungeon Masters Guide* Pg. 222)

> Magic Weapons and Critical Hits: Some weapon qualities and some specific weapons have an extra effect on a critical hit. A flaming burst weapon, for example, does extra fire damage on a critical hit. This special effect functions against creatures not subject to critical hits, such as undead, elementals, and 
>   constructs. When fighting against such creatures, roll for critical hits as you
>   would against humanoids or any other creature subject to critical hits. On a successful critical roll, apply the special effect, but do not multiply the weapon’s regular damage.

Also, many things in the book that work on critical hits specify they do not work on things that are unaffected by critical hits (i.e., Feral Death Blow & Flesh Ripper); this one does not.

Comment: Nice info! I guess @KRyan might help for this question. But the magic item might have a special effect on critical hits but I don't know if your ability will trigger, this might be DM's call.

Comment: In other words, when an attacker scores a threat against a creature that's "immune to critical hits," a critical roll is still made to see if the threat is actually a critical hit. If that critical roll is successful, *things can still happen to the target* because of the successful critical roll. (I think that creatures that say that they are immune to critical hits should often actually say instead that such creatures are immune to the *extra damage* from critical hits.)

Comment: see @MichaelDorf 's comment in my answer.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier It's common to extrapolate from existing rules when the rules are otherwise silent. That is, so far as I'm aware, in the core rules there are no *nonmagical* effects like those that quoted section mentions that *can* occur on a potential critical hit. With that in mind, it seems reasonable to extend the quoted rule to cover similar effects the game presents later, even if that means extending them to nonmagical effects.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I could not have said it better myself.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I agree but I wasn't clear enough, I meant the part of his comment that I really like is about SCORING the actual critical vs rolling the critical hit/confirming it, fine it is indeed a critical for the purpose of the trigger,  the flaming burst special property triggers, but not (IMO) Blood in the water since it's impossible to score the actual critical, in summary in my mind  confirmed critical hit that do not score (meaning doing the extra damage) does not trigger this ability but I totally agree your magic property does trigger. is it clearer? Like I also said I'd allow it.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier Please state the book and page in the Rules or a similar instance that backs up your theory that there is a difference between Scoring and Rolling/Confirming.

Comment: @CrimRei it was MichealDorf's claim but I will try to do so. for now I'm reading here: https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2oexp?Scoring-a-critical-vs-confirming-a-critical  wich is pathfinder for sure but I'm searching at least.   In PF it is indeed the same thing https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qv4  I'll look for a 3.5 reference

Comment: @CrimRei you made me see reason with that comment, thanks a lot!

Comment: You should incorporate into this answer these comments before they're moved to chat as well as a link to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167154/8610). (You're more than welcome to paraphrase or use verbatim my comments with or without attribution. I'm just glad that this issue's pretty much settled!)

Answer (score 5):

## Since confirming a critical hit is basically the same thing as scoring a critical hit and because of the critical effect that can occur on magical items even if the creature is immune to critical hits Blood in the water does indeed work in this situation.

### I first thought it did not work but I'm still leaving all the first explanation here so all points of view can be observed, see the last bullet point in the ''However'' section for the main reason of the change in opinion.

Rolling a ''critical'' (threat) is not the same as a critical ''hit'', creatures immune to critical means you would normally do a critical against such a creature (example: a human vampire) but you don't.

Furthermore a part of what you shared makes it clear to me:

> When you **score a critical hit** against an opponent, you enter a near frenzied state from the sight and smell of blood.

You need to do the critical hit and not just the threat.

On [Critical hits](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm):

When you make an attack roll and get a natural 20 (the d20 shows 20), you hit regardless of your target's Armor Class, and **you have scored a threat**. The hit **might be a critical hit** (or "crit"). To find out if it's a critical hit, you immediately make a critical roll—another attack roll with all the same modifiers as the attack roll you just made. If the critical roll also results in a hit against the target's AC, your original hit is a critical hit. (The critical roll just needs to hit to give you a crit. It doesn't need to come up 20 again.) If the critical roll is a miss, then your hit is just a regular hit.

Rolling a crit means you just scored a threat, you haven't critically ''hit'' yet you need to confirm it and for creatures immune to it you simply don't roll for the confirmation. So you just hit them without scoring a critical on them (or not if the threat range is higher than 20 and you don't have enough to hit).

[Undeads](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm) have some traits such as:

> - Not subject to critical hits or flanking .

## However

- With the new [info](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/167014/51979) @CrimRei provided, I think it might be the
  DM's call after all, unless some additional info can be found...
- **If I was to interpret this with my DM experience/opinion** I would still rule that it does not work because the way I see this is:

  > you enter a near frenzied state **from the sight and smell of blood**

  A sentence such as: **You enter a near frenzied state from the sight of the extra damage you've done via the critical hit (or felt if you are blind etc.)** would probably be more accurate, and that's what I meant by ''my interpretation''  (thanks @Hey ICan Chan)

  Since a critical hit is **supposed to occur** for it to work, I believe the PC gets
  a bonus from **making the extra critical damage** (more blood) and this buffs
  the character each time he does so, an undead wich is immune will not
  be more damaged than a regular hit, so even though it might bleed, it
  will not be more damaged so it would not trigger in my game.
- But since spellcasters are so powerful and melee builds need some love, I guess I would **probably** still **allow it**, even though I interpret it as it's not supposed to work as my first interpretation.
- @MichaelDorf added a comment that is worth mentionning:

  > **Key words here under Magic Weapons and Critical Hits '...On a
  >   successful critical roll...' whereas Blood in the Water states 'When
  >   you score a critical hit...' Further, Blood in the Water is a stance
  >   not a magical weapon, ergo a character in the Blood in the Water
  >   stance does not gain +1 bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls on a
  >   successful critical roll against an opponent immune to critical hits
  >   as it is not possible to score a critical hit.**

  - But scoring vs confirming a critical hit  is **probably** the same
    thing in 3.5 so it's irrelevant to compare the two terms.(in PF it is
    the [same thing](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qv4))  Since I could not find a source for 3.5 I asked the question: [Is there a difference between confirming a critical hit vs scoring a critical hit in 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167154/is-there-a-difference-between-confirming-a-critical-hit-vs-scoring-a-critical-hi)

Comment: I'm concerned that this might be taking things too literally. I mean, what if the defender *can* suffer critical hits but doesn't bleed… or even spews something other than blood when poked with a sword? Should the DM really nerf a dude's ability by ruling arbitrarily that the defender's spilled bodily fluid just isn't bloodlike *enough* to trigger the stance's effect? (You can totally go that far if you want—I mean, that is, after all, what the ability actually says. However, I suspect that position'll be met with some resistance.)

Comment: Well they could rephrase it as :  you enter a near frenzied state from the sight of the extra damage you've done (or felt if you are blind etc.)  that's what I meant. but as I said I would probably allow it since melee builds need some love.

Comment: Key words here under Magic Weapons and Critical Hits '...On a successful critical roll...' whereas Blood in the Water states 'When you score a critical hit...' Further, Blood in the Water is a stance not a magical weapon, ergo a character in the Blood in the Water stance does not gain +1 bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls on a successful critical roll against an opponent immune to critical hits as it is not possible to score a critical hit.

Comment: Actually, undead do not have anything about flanking, at least not in the srd